# Can I add my folder to the structure created by Android Studio 3.3.1?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I created a project in Android Studio 3.3.1, and enable the Github on the project.

The structure of the project created by Android Studio 3.3.1 with Github is just like Image 1.

1. Can I add my folder and files in the structure ? just like Image 2.
2. Can the project work well after I add my folder and files?
3. Can the Github of the project work well after I add my folder and files?

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is to put your code and other directory or files in ***app***.

But yes sure you can add it to your project. It won't change your project behaviour or Github which are only file containers. **Everything will work just fine !**

For your next step, here is the basic ***.gitignore*** content I use for my Android projects:

```
# - Android Studio (IntelliJ IDEA)
.idea/
*.iml

# - Gradle
.gradle

# - Android
build/
local.properties
captures
.externalNativeBuild
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just to add to Nicolas' answer - if you *do* want your project behaviour to change (e.g. you want to keep resources or code in there), you will need to add this new folder as an additional source-set in your build.gradle (and specify what type it is).

Comment: Thanks! My full project include image, word file, public key file and etc. so I need to add these files to my Git repository.